# What's the cleanest way to show that the only polynomials that map powers of $10$ to powers of $10$ are those of the form $p(x) = 10^mx^n$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, contest-math

My current idea is to say that we know that $p(x)$ takes the following form:

$$p(x) = a_nx^n + \dots + a_0$$

Let $x = 10^r$. As $x$ tends to infinity, the first term will dominate the rest. If $a_n$ is not a power of $10$, then eventually the first term will be so far off a power of $10$ that it is impossible for any of the other terms to "make up for it". This implies that $a_n = 10^m$ for some $m$.

Since this first term will eventually be larger than the rest of the series, the rest of the polynomial must equal $0$ for any $x = 10^r$. However, this implies that $a_{n-1}x^{n-1} + \dots + a_0$ is a polynomial with infinitely many roots, but this is only possible if it equals $0$.

Hence $p(x) = 10^mx^n$ for some integers $m,n$.

How can I make this more rigorous, and how would you solve this most elegantly?

Comment: Let me write down your question rigorously : let $p$ be a polynomial such that for every $r \in \mathbb N$ we have $p(10^r) = 10^m$ for some $m  \in \mathbb N$. Then there exist (could be zero)natural numbers $t,n$ such that $p(x) = 10^tx^n$, is that right?

Comment: Precisely, thanks for the "rigorification".

Comment: You are welcome, let me say your argument sounds right, and I will "rigorify"(?) it.

Comment: It's been done below, and well!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $p$ be of degree $d$, with leading term $a$, and let it map powers of ten to powers of ten. We have that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{p\left(10^n\right)}{10^{dn}a}=1.$$ We can therefore take $N$ such that, for $n>N$, $$\frac{1}{2}\cdot10^{dn}<\frac{p\left(10^n\right)}{a}<\frac{3}{2}\cdot10^{dn}.$$ That means, that for all sufficiently large $n$, $p\left(10^n\right)=10^{dn}a$. Since $p(x)-ax^d$ has infinitely many zeros, $p(x)=ax^d$ for all $x$, and $a$ must be a power of ten, leading to the condition you had found.

Comment: Thanks! This is perfect.